# SQL pivot columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

Query:

```
SELECT          
         item_descr
        ,shop_id
        ,COUNT(item_descr) as times
from [Order] 
group  by item_descr , shop_id
order by shop_id , times desc
```

Results:

```
item_descr  shop_id    times
product A     shop1      5
product B     shop1      3
product A     shop2      6
product B     shop2      2
```

Expected results:

```
item_descr   shop1   shop2 
product A     5        6
product B     3        2
```

How can I alter my query in order to achieve the expected result?

Comment: What version of sql-server do you have?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2 i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PIVOT

```
Select item_descr, [shop1], [Shop2]
from 
(
  Select item_descr, shop_id, times
  from [Order]  
)p
pivot 
(
  sum(times)
  for shop_id in ([shop1], [Shop2])
)pvt;
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a4dd/4)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-Server 2005+ you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).
Or try this

```
SELECT          
         item_descr
        ,sum(case when shop_id='shop1' then times end) as shop1
        ,sum(case when shop_id='shop2' then times end) as shop2        
from [Order] 
group  by item_descr
order by item_descr
```